# Downcasing & Upcasing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have built a ruby on rails app that allows for users to track their workouts. I also allow them (like a blog) to create tags for their workouts. When users add tags to their workouts, they are assisted through auto_complete to help keep things organized.

As the site has grown in popularity I am getting a little bit of clutter/inconsistency because of capitalization. Is there a way to tell the app to only create `tag.name`'s in uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: What ORM are you using? ActiveRecord? Sequel? This logic should be as close to the DB as possible, ideally in a stored proc in the DB itself, or at least in a before_save hook on the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
class Tag < AR::Base
  before_save :downcase_name

  private

  def downcase_name
    self.name.downcase!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has an [upcase](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000793) and [downcase](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000794) on the String class that will allow you to do either.  Simply call before saving the data.

For example, if you are using the [simple_auto_complete](https://github.com/grosser/simple_auto_complete) gem, you could do the following:

```
class BlogController < ApplicationController
    autocomplete_for :post, :title do |items|
        items.map {|x| x.upcase}
    end
end
```

I can't test this right now, so forgive me if there are syntax errors.

Comment: I'm not using that gem but this plugin: https://github.com/rails/auto_complete. Would that change things?

Comment: You should be able to do the same thing.  Though I don't have any experience with the auto_complete plugin and can't test anything right now.

Comment: Is this code supposed to affect the returned group.name from the table in an UPPERCASE format? If so that is not working with the above. I realize you can't test it right now so I'll fiddle with it. Just correct me if my thinking is wrong here.

Comment: That was my intention.  Is it still returning values, just not uppercased?  or is it not returning anything? or something else?

Comment: It's still returning values just not uppercased.

Comment: I dug into the auto_complete plugin code and the difference is that auto_complete does not take any block code into account.  It simply renders the resulting list back to the page.  I found a way to do it, but it requires modifying the plugin.  The simple_auto_complete plugin does take into account any block code and would work.  However, @monocle's solution is probably better anyway.